# Sql Server - Get view creation statement for existing view

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to get the statement that created a view for an existing view in SQL Server 2008?  I thought there was a stored procedure or some metadata that had this data, but I'm not finding anything.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you had a look at sp_helptext?

```
sp_helptext 'dbo.name_of_view'
```

[SQL SERVER – Stored Procedure to display code (text) of Stored Procedure, Trigger, View or Object](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/25/sql-server-stored-procedure-to-display-code-text-of-stored-procedure-trigger-view-or-object/)

Comment: The result is splitted in different rows: how to have the actual content in a single string to be used to generate a single sql statement?

Comment: Full syntax is: `sp_helptext [ @objname = ] 'name' [ , [ @columnname = ] computed_column_name ]` from [the official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql).

Answer (score 8):

Right click on the view and script it.

Answer (score 7):

It's in [sys.sql_modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175081.aspx). Other schema tables like INFORMATION_SCHEMA ones only contain the first 4000 characters of the definition (they truncate).

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the View name, then left click "SCRIPT VIEW as", then left click "ALTER TO", then left click "NEW QUERY EDITOR WINDOW" -- bingo, your there! To print, click on the script screen and then send to your printer using your toolbar printer icon or click on FILE>>PRINT. Of course, be careful to exit without making any changes.  This works the same for stored procedures.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the script as code, and copy paste it into an editor like this:

```
SELECT 
    v.TABLE_NAME, 
    v.VIEW_DEFINITION 
FROM 
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS v 
WHERE 
    v.TABLE_NAME LIKE '%%'
```

and insert the view name you want.

Comment: This worked perfectly, for newbies just put the name of your view in the middle of %% .

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps someone in the future, here's a little script I put together to output the creation script for *all* views in a database.

```sql
DECLARE @definition varchar(max)
DECLARE @view CURSOR
SET @view = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT m.definition FROM sys.views v INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = v.object_id
OPEN @view
FETCH NEXT FROM @view INTO @definition
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
    PRINT @definition
    PRINT 'GO'
    FETCH NEXT FROM @view INTO @definition
END CLOSE @view DEALLOCATE @view
```

Answer (score 0):

USER needs ViewDefinition rights to view Definition column (SQL Create Statement)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).