# Use metadata to find calculated columns in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Is there any way to use SQL Server metadata to find columns in a view that are the result of calculations/expressions? The `sys.columns` catalog view has the `Is_Computed` field, but that's returning `0` for a few fields in one of my views that are the result of a `CASE` expression, so I'm guessing it only works for calculated columns in tables. Is there any sort of similar metadata that works for views?

EDIT: What I'm trying to achieve here is an audit for some `instead of` triggers. I have a number of views that I need to make updateable with triggers, and I want to ensure that every column in the view is accounted for in the trigger so no data is lost. The trouble is that my query is flagging fields that *can't* be updated because they're the result of a computation, and I was hoping to find a way to exclude these from my results.

Comment: Not really, as a view is basically a compiled query. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To some extent, every column *could* be considered to be computed. Or consider a column which is a renaming of a column from a base table.

Comment: Fair points, both of you. I've edited my question with more of an explanation of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Any column definition containing either "=" or " as " is, de facto, a computed column. Searching for these strings will return some trivial (e simple rename) calculated columns, but it may reduce the search space sufficiently to be of use.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens You're right, and that would do the trick for me, but I'm not sure how to get the column definition for columns on a view. Any suggestion there?

Comment: @JeffRosenberg: THis link should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765323/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-view-definition-from-a-sql-server-using-plain-ado

Comment: "views that I need to make updateable with triggers" - in Codd's original formulation of what would make a "Relational Database", this would have been automatic (rule 6). It turns out there's no way to do this all programtically