# Is it Possible to get the view creation statement in sql server using sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get the view creation statement writing any query in sql sever 2008
Actually i want to copy the views from one database to another database 
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to retrieve the view definition from a SQL Server using plain ADO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765323/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-view-definition-from-a-sql-server-using-plain-ado)

Comment: This is really a deployment issue: you should have your view in source control somewhere, so the question is how to check it out and deploy it to a second database. This depends on your build/deploy process and tools. If you don't have any deployment process in place, this might be a good time to start because being able to deploy your code to any target database is extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have SSMS?  You have the option to generate scripts for all objects in a database.  You can limit it to just the views.

1. Right click on the node for the specific database in Object Explorer.
2. Select `Tasks`
3. Under `Tasks`, select `Generate Scripts`
4. Execute the wizard, selecting the options suited for your task.

This will generate a script for all your views, or allow you to select the specific views you're interested in.

@Sashenka's answer is correct, but this will let you script more than one view at a time.

Comment: From what I understood it was only for one view. But your solution offer more choice if he wants to transfer other objects. +1

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS,

1. Right click the view
2. Select `Script view as`
3. Select `CREATE To`
4. Choose `New Query Editor Window`

You can then copy the script and modify it for your new Database.

Comment: i want to do using query not using SSMS

Comment: Then the question linked by PinnyM in the comments above will help you do that without using SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/), but you can also do this in SQL Server Management Studio in a similar fashion to what I describe in this [blog post](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2012/04/24/ever-wondered-what-the-object-explorer-details-window-is-for/).

In short, open object explorer details, multiselect all your views, and script as Drop and Create from the context menu. You can now apply this script on your second server.