# Is there a way to retrieve the correct view definition in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server

If I select 'edit' in SS2005 management studio express, I am given a T-SQL 'Alter View' expression that, as given, describes the existing view. I can edit the expression and use it to alter the view.

Is there any other way of getting that T-SQL script?

As described here: [Is there a way to retrieve the view definition from a SQL Server using plain ADO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765323/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-view-definition-from-a-sql-server-using-plain-ado)
sys.sql_modules and syscomments.text both provide only a historical 'create' script which may or may not be the same as the view as it exists today: it's common to find that the 'create' script creates a view with a different name.

Comment: Won't help you, but I have to point out that all your source code should be in source control. I presume that's why you are needing to pull out from database to add to source control?

Comment: The only difference in the view definition text in `sys.sql_modules` might be the name, and only if it was renamed. SMO (not a T-SQL solution) fixes the name when scripted.

Comment: It should not be too difficult to come up with string searching/parsing code (in tSQL) that would search for `CREATE / ALTER VIEW` in sys.sql_modules and grab the name, then compare it to the actual view name. @DanGuzman suggestion is IMO better.